# Square Root and Winding Number

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f\in C(S^{1},S^{1})$ such that $w(f)=0$ where $w$ denotes winding number. Can we conclude that there exists a function $g\in C(S^{1},S^{1})$ such that $f=g^{2}$?

Comment: A more precise question would be, under these hypotheses can we conclude that there exists a function $g\in C(S^1,\mathbb C)$ such that $f=g^2$.  You cannot assume that you just pick a branch of $\sqrt{\cdot}$ on the range of $f$ and compose with $f$ (because there are functions with continuous square roots such that no continuous branch of the square root function is defined on their ranges).  What have you tried?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. Actually, in my problem $f$ belongs to $C(S^{1},S^{1})$. Now, if $f$ doesn't trace the circle, square root exists. But, what if $f$ traces the circle clockwise and then traces it counterclockwise such that winding number becomes zero. I don't know anything about this case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Parameterize the domain by $\varphi:[0,1]\to S^1$, $t\mapsto e^{2\pi it}$, and consider $\hat{f}\circ \varphi$ a lift of $f\circ \varphi$ to the universal covering space such that $\hat{f}\circ \varphi(0)=0$. Since the function has winding number zero, $\hat{f}\circ\varphi(0)=\hat{f}\circ\varphi(1)$. So we may take $\varphi\circ \frac{1}{2}\hat{f}\circ\varphi$ as $g$ such that $g^2=f$.

Comment: $f\circ \phi(0)=f\circ \phi(1)$ comes from the parametrization and has nothing to do with the winding number.

Comment: Sorry, that should be $\hat{f}$. Corrected. This definitely does depend on winding number.